# WAMP server in Windows 7 safe mode

Tags: windows, backup, windows-7

Windows 7 crashed and gives me this error message:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000022)

When I started Windows 7 in safe mode to backup my project database, I notice my WAMP server is not working, and it's displaying a red icon.

Is there anyway to either backup my database or start WAMP in safe mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like not exactly a professional sysadmin question, but it's pretty easy, yeah.

You can copy the database directory off to a USB drive (or whatever else) if the data is your primary concern, and your configs and settings are [usually, by default] be located under the particular program's install folder.

If you're not sure where your data's located, (and just as a general rule), it might be a good idea to take a disc image that you can go back to and retrieve anything from.

Comment: I copied the data folder and send it to a friend so he merged it to the project we are working on, then he exported the database and it works just fine on my Ubuntu. Thanks